# Getting length of JSON in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

```
{ "questions": [
  {
   "text": "Which colors do you see in the rainbow?",
   "answer": "A",
   "A": "RED",
   "B": "ORANGE",
   "C": "YELLOW",
   "D": "GREEN"
 },
 {
  "text": "What is sanatbek's family name?",
  "answer": "C",
  "A": "Saidov",
  "B": "Muhammadlatipov",
  "C": "Matlatipov",
  "D": "Boboyev"
 },
 {
  "text": "How many members does this company have?",
  "answer": "C",
  "A": "3",
  "B": "8",
  "C": "9",
  "D": "2"
 }
 ]
}
```

This is my `JSON` file and I need to get length of questions in `AngularJS` like this:

```
function getQuestionCount() {
    return $scope.questions.length;
}
```

Here `$scope.questions` is declared in the controller:
I have tried several solutions like

1. `return Object.keys($scope.questions).length`  this is `returning value: 6`; after displaying    `console.log($scope.questions)` . I understood that this was number of properties of my Parsed Object.
2. Then after thinking a bit,  I tried this  `return $scope.questions.data.questions.length;` this is working. However, Following error is showing on my console.

Here is My Error Message:

[image: Error message]

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined.
```

Comment: What is `$scope.questions`? Is it the array of three objects?

Comment: Yes it should be the array of three objects which is taken from `questions` key. Mr Raghu's solution is the answer for my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the ScreenShot you shared it is understood you made a HTTP GET call to retrieve the data.
After your call gets successfully completed you can set the questions length in a variable in scope.

```
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/someUrl'
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    $scope.questionsLenght = response.data.questions.length;
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  });
```

Comment: Thank you.  When I parsed from JSON I took full `response` instead of `response.data.questions` to my global variable!

Answer (score 0):

you can get length by using `for` loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.questions.length; i++) {
   $scope.data.push(angular.copy(types[i]));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

if in your controller you set your json string as

```
  $scope.questions = {
  "questions": [
  {
      "text": "Which colors do you see in the rainbow?",
      "answer": "A",
      "A": "RED",
      "B": "ORANGE",
      "C": "YELLOW",
      "D": "GREEN"
  },
 {
     "text": "What is sanatbek's family name?",
     "answer": "C",
     "A": "Saidov",
     "B": "Muhammadlatipov",
     "C": "Matlatipov",
     "D": "Boboyev"
 },
 {
     "text": "How many members does this company have?",
     "answer": "C",
     "A": "3",
     "B": "8",
     "C": "9",
     "D": "2"
 }
    ]
};
```

try

```
 $scope.questions.questions.length;
```

as the name of array inside your json string is questions